# How do i change my region to asia-east1 for cloud dataprep as it is only able to run in us-central1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

I created a Dataprep in GCP that would use data in Cloud Storage and clean it before importing it into BigQuery. But I'm facing a situation where my Dataprep would only run job in us-central1. Additionally, my cloud storage and BigQuery has to be located in the us-central1. I would like to know if there is anyway i could use region asia-southeast1 or asia-east1 to run my dataprep?

Would be extremely helpful if this can be resolve. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the regions on which you are requesting to have DataPrep run are not currently supported [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/pricing#pricing_on_and_after_march_15_2019